# VSCode Custom view container menu action contribute

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to be able to add actions to custom view container.
I've tried to use container id and title menu:

```json
"commands" : [
  {
    "command": "test_command_id",
    "title": "Test command",
    "icon": "$(zap)"
  }
],
"viewsContainers" : {
  "activitybar": [
    {
      "id": "custiom_view_container",
      "title": "Test title",
      "icon": "$(zap)"
    }
  ]
},
"menus": {
  "view/title": [
    {
      "command": "test_command_id",
      "when": "view == custiom_view_container",
      "group": "navigation"
    }
  ],
  "custiom_view_container/title": [
    {
      "command": "test_command_id",
      "when": "true",
      "group": "navigation"
    }
  ]
}
```

Non of this works, however i am able to add command for built in containers :

```json
"menus": {
  "scm/title": [
    {
      "command": "test_command_id",
      "when": "true",
      "group": "navigation"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, today. Actions are attached to views instead, and you use the regular syntax:

```json
    "view/title": [
        {
            "command": "bookmarks.refresh",
            "when": "view == bookmarksExplorer",
            "group": "navigation@10"
        },
```

Where you define the `View` to receive the action using the `when` clause.

The `scm/title` menu, on the other hand, is special, as you can notice here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus.

Maybe you could ask for a new API, exposing the same area for any contributed view.

Hope this helps